# On looping through Arguments variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm learning how to code. Well, my name is Richard and I'm learning how to code on my own, with Javascript. While I have been putting some amount of work into this consistantly during a few months, only finally I have had the means to practice on an environment where code can actually be run (before this I would put vertical lines on a notebook as indentations and practice there), and in the book I'm using as a guide (which is very good by the way, or so I feel), I found an exercise which requires to build a function which makes an array taking parameters to start and finish the array as well as a step to count that can be obviated and treated as 1 by the function (done), and then a second function that can take the values in that array and sum them, then return the result (done as well). That one was a little bit tricky while I figured out how to work with the arguments variable, but then I started thinking on how I could improve this last function, and add more functionality to it. To both really.

The step I'm stuck on is that one. I'm trying to enhance both variables to go beyond working with ONE array at a time. Instead, I want the Range function to be able to take multiple different parameters (arrays of numbers or just numbers as values), transform them all into an array and then pass all these elements to Sum, and Sum to sum them all. But I can't. I thought I could just push the number values into the array that I'm going to return to Sum(), but it's not working. I can access and move around the elements of the array that I use to test the function, but the number values given as parameters are just ignored, no matter where I put them in Args. My function looks something like this.

```
function argsPasser () { 
   var argz = [];
   for (i = 0 ; i < arguments.length ; i++) {
      if ((typeof arguments[i]) != (typeof 5)) {
         for (j = 0 ; j < arguments[i][length] ; j++) {
            argz.push(arguments[i][j]); }
      else
         argz.push(arguments[argument]; }}
   return argz; }
```

I don't know if I'm missing something in the way the control flow, or the arguments variable behaves, but this makes perfect sense to me and I don't understand why it's not doing what I want it to do. When i (index of the argument in arguments) is 0 and j (index of values within that argument) is 0, number values should be properly added to the array, no?

More than making this particular function work, I'm very interested in learning what I can do to manipulate the arguments variable and how I can make it be flexible when it comes to making functions. So even if the problem itself has no solution, learning more about this topic would be profit for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: first problem ... `[length]` should be `.length` - because you have no var called `length`

Comment: second problem `else
         argz.push(arguments[argument]; }}` should be `} else
         argz.push(arguments[argument]; }` - you've mis-placed a `}` ... it's a wonder your code isn't giving you errors in the console

Comment: third problem, missing a `)` in the second `argz.push`

Comment: fourth problem .. `arguments[argument]` should be `arguments[i]` ... really, you're not seeing any console errors?

Comment: and ... your code is simply `function argsPasser(...args) {
    return [].concat(...args);
}` - transpile it for internet exploder - `function argsPasser() {
    var _ref;
    return (_ref = []).concat.apply(_ref, arguments);
}`